# Run .bat in the foreground

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I would like to run a .bat file with VBScript.
I have a script but it is not working fine. I have no error message, but after I run the code the cmd window pops up for a sec and nothing else happens.

Do I miss something?

```
Dim WshShell
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run("""C:\Program Files (x86)\Abev\start.bat"""), 1, True
```

Comment: I think you need `WshShell.Run("""C:\...""", 1, True)` - with the `,1,True`  parameters inside the `)`. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky(v=vs.84).aspx

Comment: We can't see what the batch file does, so it's not possible to explain why it's just closing. Edit the batch file and add `pause` as the last line (which will keep the window open) and see what the console says.

Comment: rename `Start.bat` by another name and try again  and post the code of your batch too

Comment: @Hackoo: That's not it. The batch file name is fully qualified with a path and quoted, so there can't be any confusion about what's being called.

Comment: I managed to solve it using: `"cmd /K CD ` before the path.

Comment: Do you know how to add Ctrl+W `WshShell.SendKeys` to my script if the .bat file launch a java based application?

Comment: That would be `WshShell.SendKeys "^W"`. You can find more on [this site](http://www.pctools.com/guides/scripting/detail/149/?act=reference)

Comment: The [official documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c6yea83%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) is likely to be more up-to-date.

Comment: Try `
WshShell.Run("cmd /c ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Abev\start.bat"""), 1, True`